# PHP, JS : Preview with mouse hover not working, images shown by default always

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am working on a PHP project in which I am trying to show an image preview after mouse hover. I am trying it with JS script, but it's not working as intended. I have to pass the image URL in a for loop depending upon name of file. I am seeing the preview always.

Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        .test {
            display: none;
        }
        .underline {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
    echo "
        <table align='center' class='loopblock'>
            <tr class='loop'> 
                <td>Template ID Client: $client_id </th>
            </tr>
    ";

    echo "<table align='center' class='loopblock'>";

    $path = "/var/www/html/pdf/";
    $files = scandir($path);
    $files = array_diff(scandir($path), array('.', '..'));
    $counter = 1;

    foreach($files as $key) {
        echo "
            <tr class='label-loop'>
                <td class='counter' align='left' width='100' >
                    <a class='label-loop' align='left' href='/send-email.php?fileName=$key'>
                        $counter
                    </a>
                </td>
                <img id='test' src='PATH/to/image.png'>
                    Name
                </img>
                <td class='click' align='center' width='500' class='loop'>
                    <a class='loop' align='right' href='/send-email.php?fileName=$key'>
                        $key
                    </a>
                </td>    
            </tr>
        ";

        $counter++;
    }

    echo"</table>";
?>

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('span').hover(function(){
            $(this).addClass('underline'); //to make text underlined on hover
            $('#image').show(); //displays image on mouse in
        },function(){
            $(this).removeClass('underline'); //remove underline on mouse out
            $('#image').hide(); //hides image on mouse out
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following css code sets the display for a `class test`, but there is only an `id test` in here `<img id='test' src='PATH/to/image.png'>Name</img>`:

```
.test{
    display: none;
}
```

Since the images are created in a loop it should be a class not an id.

And your Javascript Code `$('#image').hide();` is used for an `id image`, which is nowhere to find in your code.

So either there is some code missing in your question, or the above might be your problem.

Edit:
Your hover also is triggered by a `span` tag, which is nowhere to find. And if you have changed the `test` to an class, you have to use `$('.test').show();`

Edit 2:

Here is a js example of how to do it with a td hover and show only the image which is inside it:

HTML / PHP PART:

```
foreach($files as $key) {
        echo "
            <tr class='label-loop'>
                <td class='counter' align='left' width='100' >
                    <a class='label-loop' align='left' href='/send-email.php?fileName=$key'>
                        $counter
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td class='click loop' align='center' width='500'>
                    <a class='loop' align='right' href='/send-email.php?fileName=$key'>
                        $key
                    </a>
                    <img class='test' src='PATH/to/image.png'>
                </td>    
            </tr>
        ";

        $counter++;
    }
```

JS PART:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('td.click').hover(function(){
            $(this).addClass('underline'); //to make text underlined on hover
            $(this).find(".test").show(); //displays image on mouse in
        },function(){
            $(this).removeClass('underline'); //remove underline on mouse out
            $(this).find(".test").hide(); //hides image on mouse out
        });
    });
```

Comment: I have changed the img parameter from id to class, but kept the name test. I have changed the JS code to $('#test').show(); and hide respectively. I am still not getting any images on hover.

Comment: Actually, I want to show the image when hovered over TD.. is that possible? I just added this img part extra. Thanks.

Comment: I edited the answer. And if you want to have it on a `td hover` you have to use `$('td').hover...;`

Comment: I tried with your modifications. Still not working. What I mean is, I want to show the image when hovering over TD. How can I add the image source inside TD then? TD is currently displaying the filename. Thank you.

Comment: I just recognized your `img tag` is inside a `tr tag` but without a `td tag` around it. Why not just move the `img part` inside one of the `td tags`?

Comment: Can you please help me out with a MySQL problem. I can move this discussion to chat, and create another question once we are done?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188676/discussion-between-we-are-borg-and-twain).